# s Open xml wordprocessingML table format issue, large gap in between certain tablerows

Tags: openxml

I'm working with tables in ms word using open XML and for some reason certain table rows have a huge gap in between them. I have attached an image of this peculiar issue. When i tried to increase the height of the tablerow, the gap in between the 2 rows would disappear. I've checked that there are no page breaks as well. Can someone please enlighten me. 
Thanks!

Here is a screenshot of the document with
[black borders turned on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tdDo.png)

Here is another screenshot of the other parts of the documents that [looks fine with the same format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erkI1.png). It is suppose to behave like this the contents should overflow to the next page.

Hi! here is a link to the document: www.dropbox.com/s/w5r2nd6m0lav4hf/sampletest.docx?dl=0

thank you.

Comment: i'm using ms office2016, and i've make the tablerow height set to auto.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your image, and your comment about tablerow height set to auto, it must be that the row height has grown too large for the bottom of that left page and it is overflowing to the next page.  Therefore you have a few options

### Option 1

to set the tablerow height to a fixed amount.

### Option 2

add some logic to your code, so that only content that is under that height will be included.  Otherwise you display something like [...] to the user to suggest them to click that row to see the full content.

### Tip

to help troubleshoot table layout problems during development is to temporarily turn on a black border on your table rows.

[image]

With this border turned on, you can easily detect row height problems with your content.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately your suggestion does not work. I have already tried to set the row height. As for turning on the black border i tried it and the border looks fine.

Comment: Can you repost your image with the borders turned on?  Embed it directly into the post and readers can better help you.  I'm interested to see the layout with the borders on. We can better help you with more information.  Thanks.

Comment: i've posted an image with borders turned on. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @user2017581 - so I see in your image with the borders turned on - the reason for the large white space on your page 19, is because the HEIGHT of the row on page 20 is too large (to high) to fit under the green row in your table for page 19.  So in my answer, under option 2, I suggest you abbreviate the content in an effort to make it shorter.  Use a visual indicator like (...) so the user can click it to view the full information if he/she wants.  If the row height of the content on page 20 (yellow / brown row) is shorter, it will fit on page 19.

Comment: Hi @Taterhead i've posted another image of the normal behaviour that the document is suppose to exhibit. The row extends from page 6 all the way to 7 and 8.

Comment: Hi @user2017581 - I think if the pink and orange sections on the last page were not there, your yellow and green row would continue without any gap on the third page.  Im sorry I cannot help more without knowing more about your code or actual openxml.  If there is a way to scramble the data and post the file here at this question, the community can better help you.

Comment: Hi @Taterhead sorry it took so long, i've uploaded an sample of the document with the mentioned issue. please advise. thank you

Comment: Thanks - I took a look at your docx.  Your design suffers from non-fixed length episode information and will not fit well within your table/column design.  If you were to make the episodes fixed and utilized some kind of indicator like ellipses [...] the user could expand the content in word.  There are add-ins and macros you can take advantage of to do this in word.  The fixed design is similar to the podcast app in iOS.  The episode descriptions run over the fixed amount, the developers put a "more..." to indicate to the users to expand the content.  I advise to redo your design like that.

Comment: here are some expansion ideas for Word:  http://www.wikihow.com/Expand-and-Collapse-in-Microsoft-Word

Comment: thanks @Taterhead for the advice, i will try it out. It's strange when i copy and paste everything within the document to another document, everything looks fine.